# Problem with importing WKT to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, well-known-text

I'm trying to import WKT (http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_wkt.py?id=2413177&params=0 - boundary of one of districts of Łódź) into PostGIS database and convert it to geometry. I've created table 'districts' with 'the_geom geometry', id and name of the district.
When I tried to insert data with

```
INSERT INTO districts (name, the_geom) VALUES ('Polesie', ST_GeomFromText('<<<WKT goes here>>>', 4326))
```

the the_geom field is left empty. In fact, even query like `SELECT ST_GeomFromText('...', 4326)` returns empty query. I also tried to create text field in the table, insert WKT data in there and then run `UPDATE districts SET the_geom=ST_GeomFromText('...', 4326)` but it doesn't work.
I tried to use query from http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html and it worked.

Could anyone help me with this one? Am I doing something wrong, or the WKT is just too big?

Definition of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE dzielnice
(
  name character varying(30),
  the_geom geometry,
  wkt text,
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT dzielnice_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT dzielnice_id_key UNIQUE (id)
)
```

Comment: Have you tried "VALUES" in your insert?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that. I used VALUES of course, VALUE would throw an error AFAIR.
Still, even SELECT ST_GeomFromText('...', 4326) doesn't work, and that's probably the simplest query you can make.
I tried with different WKT (simple POINT and some small multipolygon) and my query worked perfectly.

Comment: If `SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT (1 1)',4326);`does not return anything you must have something wrong in your installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get any error message? If not, there is no error and your data is there. It is just a limit how much data pgAdmin shows.

You can increase that value in options, I think default is 256 bytes or characters.

You can check if your geoemtry is there for instance by querying number of points

ST_Npoints(the_geom)